# push button from background class

Tags: java, android, list, android-activity, android-context

I have `BroadcastReceiver`, when it gets certain information I want to press a button inside the activity .

The button delete\update row inside the list inside this activity .

How it can be done ?

I tried something like this:

```
// trying to invalidate !!!

    try {               
     Target_Activity ti = new Target_Activity();
     ti.refresh.performClick();     
     Log.d("Pleaase", "work");
         } catch (Exception e) {

         }
```

But its not working, my guess is that I need to give somehow the method the context of the activity but I do not really know .

So all I want is to push refresh button in  `Target_Activity` if possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, when you load MainActivity, it goes to ActivityB, and ActivityB clicks the button created in MainActivity. You must make sure that the button which you are trying to click is not null.

good luck

MainActivity

```
  package com.example.testproject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        RelativeLayout lyt;
        public static Button button;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            lyt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
            button = new Button(this);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked the button",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            lyt.addView(button);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

ActivityB

```
    package com.example.testproject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity a = new MainActivity();
        Button button =  MainActivity.button;
        button.performClick();
    }
    }
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.testproject.ActivityB" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```